# Click through images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know the best way to add a next and back button to click through my images. The images currently scroll left & right when you roll over a hotspot.

I have tried adding anchors to images, which works but is a bit messy.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="scrollWrapper" >    
   <div class="scrollableArea" >

       <div class="boxer">
           <img src="img/apples" />
       </div>
        <div class="boxer">
           <img src="img/apples" />
       </div>
        <div class="boxer">
           <img src="img/apples" />
       </div>


   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sure there's more code to it than what you've posted (i.e. JavaScript).

Comment: Yes, there is for the scrollable hotspots. But im thinking i would like to remove that and just have next/back buttons as scrollable area is a bit jumpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a plugin, read this: http://blog.wearelaunchbox.com/?p=1029

This is great tutorial on how to make your own slider that you're talking about with very little jQuery.  Let me know if this helps.

EDIT:  Here is a jsfiddle running the right function how you want it, reworked from the tutorial..  You can take this code and rewrite the same function to make it go the other way.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ug3fu/3/

Comment: It,s close. That one is using anchor tags and id's. There for a button for each image. I would like just one next and one previous button.

Comment: You can accomplish that pretty easily with this tutorial.  Instead of finding the anchor tag, just tie a prev and next button with an animate left and right.  You can store the left and right animates in a variable.  That code can be changed at will.  I think there is source code up there, I would download it and play around with it.

Comment: So, your code would look something like `$(".prev").click( function () { $(".rolodexSlider").stop().animate({ left: /*distance*/, }, 500 ); return false;` You could store this in a variable and write another one for right using the same syntax but with a different distance.

Comment: Cool thanks, my images are different sizes, so the distance is different every time?

Comment: Edited my answer, take a look a the fiddle.

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for, would you mind marking it as such?  :)

Comment: The problem is the distance is different each time as the image sizes will be different widths

Comment: In that case, I would probably recommend trying to see if you can size your images the same.  Usually sliders have a set width and don't really stray from that.  You could write a script that would detect how wide and image would be and to constrain with that, but that might be a little weird.  There is also the lightbox plugin to check out as well - http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use a plugin to handle your slideshow, I like [Malsup's cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), here's an example of what you're trying to do: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Comment: +1 I've used that plugin myself in high traffic production sites.  It's fantastic and can handle creating the prev/next and item buttons for you.

Comment: Thanks, that might be the best way. My wrapper width is 100% and my images are about 20%. I imagine it shouldnt be to much trouble to adapt the cycle plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure, it should be able to do almost anything you want with some css tweaks and fiddling with the options.